# Is there a standard way to apply different field values to linestring vertices?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, linestring, geometrycollection

In QGIS I have several 3D points that I am creating a linestring from and each point could have a different value in one of the fields like "type". I want to somehow create the linestring and be able to get individual info for each GPS point.    The 'type' only has 4 choices A,B,C or D.  The line could have 50 vertices.   I looked at multipoint also and it also seems to allow only the same values in each field for each point in the multipoint feature.

I'll have hundreds of lines when this is finished.

Is there another data type or a way to group points into a collection from which I can make a line?

Comment: A linestring cannot store separate attribute data for each vertex. If you give each group of points a unique ID, you can use the ID to join the line to the points, or vice versa, while still keeping them as separate layers.